# No provider for InjectionToken Global Config! error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

After updating from angular 11 to 13 all my child routes became broken and i am getting this error

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ArchViewModule)[InjectionToken Global Config -> InjectionToken Global Config -> InjectionToken Global Config -> InjectionToken Global Config -> InjectionToken Global Config -> InjectionToken Global Config]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Global Config!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:11105)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272)
    at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21800)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272)
    at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21800)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272)
    at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21800)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11272)
```

What is Global Config InjectionToken? Did't find any info about it or how it is provided to any angular app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No for InjectionToken Config in Angular Application after upgrading to webpack 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867203/no-for-injectiontoken-config-in-angular-application-after-upgrading-to-webpack-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem (after updating Angular from 11 to 13).

In my case the error was:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n)[InjectionToken Global Config -> InjectionToken Global Config -> InjectionToken Global Config]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Global Config!
at SC.get (main.078853b013d2848c.js:1:61264)
at BF.get (main.078853b013d2848c.js:1:62617)
at BF.get (main.078853b013d2848c.js:1:62617)
at BF.get (main.078853b013d2848c.js:1:62617)
at Ew.get (main.078853b013d2848c.js:1:90367)
at Object.get (main.078853b013d2848c.js:1:87205)
at Nv (main.078853b013d2848c.js:1:29111)
at Bv (main.078853b013d2848c.js:1:29902)
at f (main.078853b013d2848c.js:1:69189)
at Xl.n.ɵfac [as factory] (main.078853b013d2848c.js:1:744197)
```

I've found out that the problem was related to a library I am using in my Angular project (which is [Anguar Material Design Progress Buttons](https://github.com/michaeldoye/mat-progress-buttons)).

This library has to be imported as follows (inside the AppModule):

```
import { MatProgressButtonsModule } from 'mat-progress-buttons';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [MatProgressButtonsModule.forRoot(), ...],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

*but* i was missing the `forRoot()` call for `MatProgressButtonsModule` (which was **not** necessary before updating Angular: it wasn't present and the App always worked perfectly fine).

Probably your problem is of the same nature: check that all the libraries you're using are imported in a correct way inside the AppModule, calling `forRoot()` when required.